# Dragons and Dragon Slayers

Tags: story, combinatorics, optimization

- In the Kingdom, there are 7 dragons and 7 dragon slayers.
- Each dragon has ($\text{index}\times10000$) hit points (i.e. $10,000\to70,000$).
- Each dragon slayer does ($\text{index}\times1000$) damage (i.e. $1,000\to7,000$).
- The local King asks the dragon slayers to slay all the dragons.
- Each slay round consists of each dragon slayer each attacking a single dragon.
- A dragon slayer cannot attack the same dragon again until he has attacked all remaining dragons.
- Dragon slayers don't die.
- The King figures it will take them at least $10$ slay rounds (hit point to damage ratio), and offers to pay $2,000,000-(\text{number of slay rounds taken}\times100,000)$.

**Can it be done?**

Comment: After a slayer attacks each dragon once, may it attack the same dragon 3 times, or must it attack a different dragon each of the last 3 rounds?

Comment: @noedne; it's in rotation, so abcdefgac isn't allowed unless b has died in the process.

Comment: Can slayers attack the same dragon in the same round?

Comment: @noedne; yes, excess damage is wiped out though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Yes, it can be done.

Each round, every slayer attacks for a total of 28,000 damage. So,

> If we first reduce player damage by 1000, then it will be easier. I have come up with this table:
>
> `Rounds   10000    20000   30000     40000     50000   60000         70000`
> `1        1,3,6            2         7,5               4`
> `2                                             2,3,4,5               7,6,1`
> `3               2,3,4,5,6                     7,1`
> `4                                   2                 1,3,5,6,7     4`
> `5                         7         1,4,6             2             3,5`
> `6                         1,4,5,6   3,7                             2`
> `7                         2,3       5         6       4             1,7`
> `8                                          1,2,3,4,5,7              6`
> `9                                                     1,2,3,5,6,7   4`
> `10                                                    4             1,2,3,5,6,7`